# MATLAB: vectorize for-loop containing circshift

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I have the following for-loop that I'd like to vectorize. However, inside the for-loop I use circshift. Is there a way to perform the for-loop using vectorization, or at least optimize it? It runs very slowly as strt, stop and M increase their size.

```
indx = 0;

M = magic(16);
v = M(:,1);

strt=-5;
stop=+5;

result = zeros(4, length(strt:stop), 4);
for ii=strt:stop
    tmp = circshift(M, [0 ii])*v;
    tmp = tmp/norm(tmp);

    indx = indx+1;
    result(:, indx, :) = reshape( tmp(:,1), 4,4);
end
```

Comment: its probably [-5;5] right?

Comment: @Finn Yes, I changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shifting that huge `2D` array, `M` with `circshift` would surely be expensive. So, one trick could be to shift around the `1D` array `v` instead in the other direction and keep `M` as it is. So, we need just one edit to replace :

`circshift(M, [0 ii])*v` with `M*circshift(v,-ii)`.

The runtimes for `M` as `(2500 x 2500)` sized array with the original and proposed approaches at my end were -

```
----------------------- With Original approach
Elapsed time is 0.803823 seconds.
----------------------- With Proposed approach
Elapsed time is 0.137444 seconds.
```

Comment: Well, I guess I was 1min late ;)

Answer (score 2):

When you increase the size of `M`, the function `circshift` becomes the most time consuming part of your code. This time is increasing with the size.

One helpful step is to change `circshift(M, [0 ii])*v` to `M*circshift(v,-ii)`. Note that they produce the same `tmp`, but the second one deals with `v` which is just one column of `M`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be represented as a 2D convolution , so this code tested in Octave, for Matlab some changes needed that explained in the comments:

```
%temp created however order of column reversed relative to  your 'tmp'
temp=conv2([M M(:,1:10)] , circshift(flipud(v).', [0 , 5]),'valid');
%only availabe in Octave. Norm of columns computed . In Matlab use for loop to compute norm of each column
nrm=norm(temp,'cols');
%divide temp by norm
temp = bsxfun(@rdivide,temp,nrm);
% The result. Order of slices reversed
result = reshape(temp,[4,4,size(temp,2)])
```